# Spot beam (Coverage area) and beam width

Tags: wireless, antenna, dsp

Spot beam is simply a manifestation of my simulation model.  It says that given a certain azimuth angle and an elevation angle, then what is the area of circle in space at a distance R away from the origin.  For this I have to  assume a conical geometry, and so the further you move away from the apex of a cone, the larger the circular area of the base of the cone.  This marks the spot beam and it is the area of interest in space.

Beamwidth does not grow with distance (else you're assuming that its gaining power from somewhere).  It stays constant, and with my assumption that its circular, it marks the area within the spot beam where there is relevant energy, either transmitted (incident) or gain (observant). And therefore, for a given spot beam (an area of interest in the 3 dimensional space) I'm first trying to see if that area is greater than the beam width

So my question is: What is the relationship between a spot beam and beam width? If I assume a cone, will the angle, theta be equal to the beamwidth? or what angle should I take so that the area of circle in space at a distance R away from the origin can be calculate?

Comment: Your first sentence is the key. If you're asking a question about something that is unique to your "simulation model", how can we possibly answer it without knowing what that model is, and what your definition of "spot beam" is? Without more context, this sounds like a math or physics question. For one thing, what kind of energy are we talking about? Acoustic? Light? RF? Something else?

Comment: The Beamwidth is the total apex angle or Field of View and the Spot Beam is the base of the cone that is projected by that Beamwidth θ at distance R. Usually defined as the 50% Intensity threshold, but not always.

Comment: Apart from answers you get here, I am sure the [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) folks would love to get their teeth into your question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

IR LEDs and lasers are often spec as half beamwidth wheras visible LEDs are spec'd as full angle Theta.  But I suspect you are trying to see if you are in the footprint of the next DTH Bollywood satellite spot beam.
[image]

Comment: OP's question is unclear, but he does specify "wireless" in the tags. What do LEDs and lasers have to do with this?

Comment: yah spot beam and fooprint refer to DTV type geostationary satellites. and India has a huge demand for these Direct to Home or DTH satellites .. lucky for them.. just teasing ya Nidhi, what are you designing?