# Spectrum Sensing

Tags: antenna, model, sensing, spectrum

I am trying to find the maximum range of a directional antenna whose beamwidth can be varied. The goal is to understand if  a particular (x,y) user lies within the antenna. The distance between the transmitter and the user(x,y) can be calculated using the distance formulae.

I have attached my code for your reference. Here I have assumed `Dmax` to be 29, although that is the one that needs to be found out.

```
count = np.zeros(24)
def checkPoint(Dmax, x, y, percent, startAngle,index):

    # calculate endAngle
    endAngle = 360 / percent + startAngle

    # Calculate polar co-ordinates
    polarradius = math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)
    if (x!=0 and y!=0):
        Angle = math.atan(y / x)
        degrees = math.degrees(Angle)       
    if (x==0):
        degrees=90
    elif (x==0 and y<0):
        degrees=270
    if (x>=0 and y<0): 
    
        degrees=360+degrees;
    
    elif (x<0 and y<0):
    
        degrees=180-degrees
    
    elif (x<0 and y>0):
    
        degrees=180+degrees;
    print(degrees)
    

    # Check whether polarradius is less
    # then the maximum range
    # Angle is between startAngle and
    # endAngle or not    
    if (degrees >= startAngle and degrees <= endAngle
                        and polardistance < Dmax):
        print("Point (", x, ",", y, ") "
            "exist in the circle sector",i)
        count[i]+=1
    else:
        print("Point (", x, ",", y, ") "
            "does not exist in the circle sector",i)
```

## Driver code

```
for i in range(0,50):    
    x=(int(random.randint(-29,29)))
    y= (int(random.randint(-29,29)))
    Dmax = 29
    percent, startAngle = 24, 0

    for i in range(0,24):
        checkPoint(Dmax, x, y, percent, startAngle,i)
        startAngle= startAngle+ 15 
        print(startAngle)
print(count)
max_value = np.max(count)
print(max_value)
max_index = np.where(count == max_value)
print(max_index)
```

Comment: hi welcome here! So, what is your precise question?

Comment: To find the Maximum range(Dmax) of a directional antenna

Comment: so, what's the *precise* question? Is it "What is the maximum range of an antenna?"

Comment: because then, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/573108/simple-radio-transmitter-range/573118#573118

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50454/spot-beam-coverage-area-and-beam-width. I found this to be beneficial,  assume that h is the maximum range of the beam, I am struggling to find the radius (r). Since if r is known, for a particular beamwidth, we can find h

Comment: mukesh, there **is** no maximum range. As said. That cone only shows how much the power distributes over a larger area with growing distance.